# Raspberry pi : export gpio fails

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I compiled Raspbian for my raspberry pi (model B+) and I wanted a gpio to be exported when booting the kernel. I edited the file /arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm_2708_gpio.c

```
static int __init bcm2708_gpio_init(void){

gpio_request(7, "external_gpio_7");
gpio_export(7, true);
printk("GPIO MESSAGE\n");
return platform_driver_register(&bcm2708_gpio_driver);
}
```

The code with gpio_request gpio_export and the printk is the lines I added. Once I launch raspbian and I type dmesg in the terminal, I can see my message "GPIO MESSAGE" being printed but when I go into /sys/class/gpio/, I can't see gpio7 (but I still can export it manually from my terminal). And I already did this on other boards without problems.

Does someone know why my gpio is not exported when booting?

Thanks!